# How can Perl alternate between colors while printing to terminal?

Tags: perl, colors, terminal

Why doesn't the following script work?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Term::ANSIColor ':constants';
my @colors = ( BLUE, GREEN );
my $select;

my @data = 1 .. 10;
print { $colors[$select++ % @colors] } $_, "\n" for @data;
```

outputs:

> `Can't use string ("") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at - line 9.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `print { $fh } @strings` syntax ([documented here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html)). The thing in curly braces (which are actually optional in simple cases) is interpreted as a file handle. Here, you pass a string instead of the file handle object, so Perl looks for a global variable with the name of the string. Unfortunately, this string contains funky command sequences (which happen to be unprintable) instead of some usable variable name.

Solution: don't use that weird syntax, and just do

```
my $select = 0;
print $colors[$select++ % @colors], $_, "\n" for 1 .. 10;
```

Comment: I concede defeat, that's a lot simpler looking!

Comment: Wow, this is really strange. I wasn't expecting to have to provide a list here. The filehandle syntax was chosen because the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ANSIColor) shows examples like `print BOLD BLUE "Text\n";`. In fact, it does mention something about `print BOLD BLUE "Text\n"` being slightly different from `print BOLD, BLUE, "Text\n"`. I can definitely use this answer, but I still feel that something here is unexplained.

Comment: @Zaid `print BOLD BLUE $text` is ambiguous and can be parsed as `print {BOLD} BLUE($text)` or `print +BOLD(BLUE($text))`. But if the function `BOLD` has been defined at parse time (this is the case with imported subs), it will chose the 2nd interpretation so everything is fine. I'd rather use commas as they avoid this madness.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what you want:

```
print @{[ $colors[$select++ % @colors] ]}, $_, "\n" for @data
```

I will hazard a guess at an explanation: the `@{[  ]}` interpolates the value of a function. I've used them before in a HEREDOC.